# Vectorising two similar functions in R works for one

Tags: r, function, vectorization

Today, I came across a problem: two almost identical functions work as intended before vectorisation, but after it, one works fine, and another one returns an error.

I am examining the robustness of various estimators with respect to different transformations of residuals and aggregating functions. Quantile Regression and Least Median of Squares are particular cases of what I am doing.

So I wrote the following code to see how the Least Trimean of Squares is going to work and found out that it works fine if model parameters are supplied as different arguments, but fails if they come in a vector. For instance, I need the first function for plotting (it is convenient to use `outer(...)` to get a value matrix for `persp` or just supply `f(x, y)` to `persp3d` from `library(rgl)`, but the second one for estimation (R optimisers are expecting a vector of inputs as the first argument over which the minimisation is going to be done).

MWE:

```
set.seed(105)
N <-  204
x <- rlnorm(N)
y <- 1 + x + rnorm(N)*sqrt(.1+.2*x+.3*x^2)
# A simple linear model with heteroskedastic errors

resfun <- function(x) return(x^2)
# Going to minimise a function of squared residuals...
distfun <- function(x) return(mean(quantile(x, c(0.25, 0.5, 0.5, 0.75)))) 
# ...which in this case is the trimean

penalty <- function(theta0, theta1) {
  r <- y - theta0 - theta1*x
  return(distfun(resfun(r)))
}

pen2 <- function(theta) {
  r <- y - theta[1] - theta[2]*x
  return(distfun(resfun(r)))
}

penalty(1, 1) # 0.5352602
pen2(c(1, 1)) # 0.5352602

vpenalty <- Vectorize(penalty)
vpen2 <- Vectorize(pen2)

vpenalty(1, 1) # 0.5352602
vpen2(c(1, 1))

Error in quantile.default(x, c(0.25, 0.5, 0.5, 0.75)) : 
missing values and NaN's not allowed if 'na.rm' is FALSE
```

Why does `vpen2`, being vectorised `pen2`, choke even on a single input?

Comment: For `vpen2(c(1,1))` the elements of the vector `c(1,1)` are given one by one to the parameter `theta` - so every time `theta[2]` is empty. Examine it by putting a `print(theta)` in your function `pen2()`.

Comment: You'll want to put your vector in a list, e.g. `vpen2(list(c(1, 1)))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [jogo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5414452/jogo) pointed out, `vpen2` reads the elements of the input vector and tries to take the first one. The right way to go is to use something like

```
a <- matrix(..., ncol=2)
apply(a, 1, pen2)
```

This will return a vector of values from `vpar2` evaluated at each row of the matrix.

Comment: Downvote wasn't me, but I'd just point out that you might have meant `apply(a, 1, pen2)`, not the vectorized version.

Comment: @WeihuangWong Yes, of course, you are right. Fat fingers and absent-mindedness are my trusty friends.